# Assigning parent to spark row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe like this:

```
val dataSeq = Seq(
    (20, "data", 0),
    (21, "data", 1),
    (99, "data", 2),
    (99, "data", 3),
    (99, "data", 4),
    (25, "data", 5),
    (99, "data", 6),
    (99, "data", 7))

val df = dataSeq.toDF("A", "B", "index")
df.show
+---+----+-----+
|  A|   B|index|
+---+----+-----+
| 20|data|    0|
| 21|data|    1|
| 99|data|    2|
| 99|data|    3|
| 99|data|    4|
| 25|data|    5|
| 99|data|    6|
| 99|data|    7|
+---+----+-----+
```

In this case, the 99s are children of the non-99 code before the first instance of it - i.e. indices 2,3,4 are children of index 1 and indices 6,7 are children of index 5. I want to create a df consisting of only 99 codes, but with an additional column for the parent index in order to group them later

I've separated the dataframes by code using the following:

```
val code20Df = df.filter(df("A") === 20)
val code21Df = df.filter(df("A") === 21)
val code25Df = df.filter(df("A") === 25)
val code99Df = df.filter(df("A") === 99)
```

I want the code99Df to look like:

| A | B | index | parentIndex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | data | 2 | 1 |
| 99 | data | 3 | 1 |
| 99 | data | 4 | 1 |
| 99 | data | 6 | 5 |
| 99 | data | 7 | 5 |

Is there an aggregate function that will allow me to keep track of the "parent", assign that value to children and then reset that value once the row value is not 99, or will I have to resort to using a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.orderBy("index").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn(
    "parentId", 
    when(
        col("A")===99, 
        last(
            when(col("A")=!=99, col("index")), 
            ignoreNulls=true
        ).over(w)
    )
).show
+---+----+-----+--------+
|  A|   B|index|parentId|
+---+----+-----+--------+
| 20|data|    0|    null|
| 21|data|    1|    null|
| 99|data|    2|       1|
| 99|data|    3|       1|
| 99|data|    4|       1|
| 25|data|    5|    null|
| 99|data|    6|       5|
| 99|data|    7|       5|
+---+----+-----+--------+
```

First we can mark the required indexes as candidates for `parentId`, let's pretend that we have such column and call it `candidateParentId`:

```
when(col("A")=!=99, col("index")).as("candidateParentId")
```

I.e., for rows that have `A==99` - `candidateParentId` would be `null`, and for rows `A!=99` - would contain `index` of that rows.

Then for each row we need to go backwards and take first non-null `candidateParentId`:

```
val w = Window.orderBy("index").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
last(when(col("A")=!=99, col("index")), ignoreNulls=true).over(w)
```

This would fill `candidateParentId` for every row, but we want only for rows `A==99`, so we add that one final check to get our `parentId` column:

```
when(
        col("A")===99, 
        last(
            when(col("A")=!=99, col("index")), 
            ignoreNulls=true
        ).over(w)
    )
```